# Will PgBouncer reuse postgresql session sequence cache?

Tags: postgresql, pgbouncer

I want to use postgres sequence with cache `CREATE SEQUENCE serial CACHE 100`.
The goal is to improve performance of 3000 usages per second of `SELECT nextval('serial');` by ~500 connection/application threads concurrently.

The issue is that I am doing intensive autoscaling and connections will be disconnected and reconnected occasionally leaving "holes" of unused ids in the sequence each time a connection is disconnected.

Well, the good news might be that I am using a [PgBouncer heroku buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-pgbouncer/blob/master/bin/gen-pgbouncer-conf.sh) with transaction pool mode.

My question is: will the transaction pool mode solve the "holes" issues that I described, will it reuse the session in a way that the next application connection will take this session from the pool and continue using the cache of the sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the setting of `server_reset_query`.  If you have that set to `DISCARD ALL`, then sequence caches are discarded before a server connected is handed out to a client.  But for transaction pooling, the recommended `server_reset_query` is empty, so you will be able to reuse sequence caches in that case.  You can also use a different `DISCARD` command, depending on your needs.